# Premetrics, where are they useful?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premetric#Premetrics) defines a premetric as a function $d : X\times X \to \mathbb R$ such that

- $d(x,y) \ge 0$
- $d(x,x) = 0$.

For me these axioms are so weak that I am wondering where they are used, do you know any examples? I can not find anything, and when I look for the term premetric I just found references to pseudometrics.

Comment: The vertex set of a strongly connected directed graph has a natural premetric given by the shortest directed path from the vertex $x$ to the vertex $y$ (the empty path has length $0$). The strongly connected condition is necessary as otherwise the premetric isn't well-defined. In general, this is **not** a metric. This definition can also be extended to such digraphs with weighted edges. One might then suspect that this is a useful notion in network theory but I don't know enough to expand on this.

Comment: Paramedics are *always* useful; parametrics, only in *school*. :-)